# Are there inherent flaws when deploying a Python application as a shared network folder?

Tags: python, windows, deployment

I recently came across an interesting way to deploy a Python application to users on a local Windows network:

- Install Python [properly](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/) on user machines (the same minor version on all machines)
- Create a shared network folder
- Copy Python application files into the folder
- Create a .bat script that tweaks the PYTHONPATH and invokes the main .py file
- Copy shortcut onto each Windows desktop
- User invokes the application by double-clicking the shortcut

This deployment option isn't listed as a [shipping option](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/#shipping-great-code) in the Python Guide. Are there any obvious gotchas to having multiple users run the same .py files from a shared location?

(Assume that any other resource sharing is handled correctly by the application(s), e.g. they don't try to write to a shared file.)

(I'm open to suggestions on making this a more valid and answerable question.)

Answer (score 0):

Your creative approach requires your PC to always be on, and the network working, and what about performance, when is it safe to update python, what about someone who wants to use your app away from your network, ...

Why not package the script into an exe? I've used py2exe http://www.py2exe.org/

This has the added advantage that it's not so easy for people to play with your script and 'adapt' it in ways that might break it. The exe is a lot bigger than the script, but we're not talking hundreds of megs. It doesn't need an installer or anything like that.